# Can iOS apps retrieve user access logs after being deleted?

Tags: ios, logs, ipados

Specifically, I used an iPad app while it was offline, then deleted it. I assume that it keeps logs of access into the app and whatnot. Can an app be able to gain access to these offline logs after the app is deleted by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No in general and by design. When the app is deleted, the os removed the container in which the app saves data. Unless the app saves data in a group container or runs on a jailbroken device and stuffs logs outside the sandbox, even reinstalling the app won’t recover the deleted data.

Comment: I see. And group containers are only possible if there are multiple apps developed by the same developer within the OS, correct?

Comment: @tradingplaces22 precisely. Think MS office with group containers so they can share credentials and avoid having you sign in to each app you download to license it. Their design could be reverse engineered for a master class in analytics, shared keychain use, lighting up features based on license type, ongoing surveillance, etc...